# Why is get_post_format() for "Standard" returns empty

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, themes

I've enabled custom posts types

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'link', 'gallery', 'status', 'quote', 'image' ) );
```

The default post type is set on `Standard`, and it works for all but the `Standard` type, when I have a standard post the `get_post_format()` return empty. did I miss something in enabling them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because "Standard" is not a format itself - it simply implies that the post **has no formats**.

> ...which is somewhat deceptive, given it's listed in the Format meta-box as a format to choose

I think "standard" quite clearly implies what it means. If you're creating a site in which a post is never "standard", then fallback to a default:

```
if ( ! $format = get_post_format() )
    $format = 'gallery';
```

Alternatively, hook onto `wp_insert_post` and enforce a format if one has not already been set.

```
function wpse_58121_set_default_format( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! get_post_format( $post_id ) )
        set_post_format( $post_id, 'gallery' );
}
```

Comment: ...which is somewhat deceptive, given it's listed in the Format meta-box as a format to choose. This ties into why it's it's [not possible](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-standard-post-format) to remove the Standard "format" (bar the gymnastics in the accepted answer) even if you never intend to use it.

Comment: Check out my revision for some further comments on the matter.